# How do I create a column in pandera that contains a valid datetime as a string?

Tags: pandera

I'm working with a schema that has a column which contains string representations of datetimes. I'd like to make sure that the string is a valid datetime. It looks like doing this with regex and `str_matches` is not sufficient (and challenging to maintain).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a custom strategy:

```py
YYYY_MM_DD_REGEX = r"^[0-9]{4}-[1-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$"

def datetime_string_strategy(
    pandera_dtype: pa.DataType,
    strategy: Optional[st.SearchStrategy] = None,
    *,
    value,
):
    if strategy is None:
        return st.pandas_dtype_strategy(
            pandera_dtype,
            strategy=hypothesis.strategies.datetimes().map(
                lambda date: date.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
            ),
        )
    return strategy.filter(lambda x: x == value)


@extensions.register_check_method(statistics=["value"], strategy=datetime_string_strategy)
def custom_datetime_string_match(pandas_obj, *, value):
    return pandas_obj.str.match(value) == True

class SampleSchema(pa.SchemaModel):
    some_datetime: Series[str] = pa.Field(
        alias="real-column-name", custom_datetime_string_match=YYYY_MM_DD_REGEX
    )
```

Note that this also works with dates - you just need to swap in `hypothesis.strategies.dates()`.